# Firestore changing document if user is offline?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to have friends page, where I could see who is online and who is offline.
Updating document to set user online is no problem.
I have a useEffect that checks if currentUser exists and it would update isOnline to true.
But is there a way to set isOnline to false, when user leaves Website.
If user where to click signOut then its fine I could first update isOnline to false then signOut, but if user just exits how do I know he is offline? sorry if my question is confusing.

Comment: The easiest  way to know that a  user presently  has your friends page  loaded in his browser is to use polling. Polling  means that the user will periodically  make requests to your friends page.

Comment: Since you added reactjs tag, maybe look at https://blog.bitsrc.io/polling-in-react-using-the-useinterval-custom-hook-e2bcefda4197

Comment: I will read it, thanks for trying to help :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually looking for a system to detect "presence". As explained in the Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence), you can use the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) to add presence to your Cloud Firestore based app.

This Firebase Blog [article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system.html) from 2013 is also interesting to read, to get more details on the Realtime Database presence system.

Comment: Thank you allot, yes that is what i was looking for.